# How do I add label for reference from a loop

Tags: cross-referencing, loops

```
\foreach \n in {5,-30,65,75}{
     \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/plots_for_theta_0_at\n.eps}
    \caption{PD controller response at $\theta_0 = \n^\circ$}
    \label{fig: response at \n}
\end{figure}
}
```

I did this, however when I reference response at 5 it does not work. Is there a workaround as I actually need to add 8 of these figures in a row please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: please extend your code fragment to complete small document (Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem. If I insert your fragment in an article document, I can't reproduce your problem. So we need how you test/use your code.

Answer (score 1):

I try to compose MWE using your code fragment. This MWE works fine, so it is not clear in what your document differ from mine MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {5,-30,65,75}{
     \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/plots_for_theta_0_at\n.eps}
    \caption{PD controller response at $\theta_0 = \n^\circ$}
    \label{fig: response at \n}
\end{figure}
}
See figured \ref{fig: response at 5}, \ref{fig: response at -30}, \ref{fig: response at 65}  and \ref{fig: response at 75}
\end{document}
```

[image]